# Function runs after block of code even though it is called before

Tags: ios, swift

Ok I don't get this. I have written some code for forward geocoding, I have an UITextField that you write name of a city in and after you press the enter button it is dismissed and at the same time the function is called to determine if the UITextField contains a valid input. If there is an error it is saved in a bool variable which value is changed in the function. I have print statements all over the place and from the console output I can see that the function ran after the if condition, but it is called before... what? Can somebody explain me what is going on? Code:

```
var locationError: Bool?

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)

    forwardGeocoding(textField.text!)
    print("forward geocoding ran 1st time")

    print(locationError)
    if locationError == true {
        print("Error")
    } else if locationError == false {
        print("Success")
    } else if locationError == nil {
        print("No value for locationError")
    }

    return false
}

func forwardGeocoding(address: String) -> CLLocation? {
    var userLocation: CLLocation?
    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Geocoding error: \(error)") 
            self.locationError = true
            return
        }
        if placemarks?.count > 0 {
            print("Placemark found")
            self.locationError = false
            let placemark = placemarks?.first
            let location = placemark?.location
            let coordinate = location?.coordinate
            print("Settings location: \(coordinate!.latitude), \(coordinate!.longitude)")
            if let unwrappedCoordinate = coordinate {
                let CLReadyLocation: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: unwrappedCoordinate.latitude, longitude: unwrappedCoordinate.longitude)
                userLocation = CLReadyLocation
            }
        }
    })
    return userLocation
}
```

Console output:

```
forward geocoding ran 1st time
nil
No value for locationError
Placemark found
Settings location: 48.8567879, 2.3510768
```

Comment: This is partially a guess on my part, but I think the reason this happens is because the code in the function is in a closure, which causes it to run asynchronously with the rest of the code. Try putting a print above the userLocation variable in the function and see what happens.

Comment: What is `placemarks` ? Is it an array?

Answer (score 0):

Try multi threading it...

```
let queue = NSOperationQueue()
    queue.addOperationWithBlock() {
          NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the completion handler as your function parameter:

`func forwardGeocoding(address: String, completionHandler: (placemarks: String? or [Array of any type], error: NSError?) -> ()) -> CLLocation?`

modify your if block:

```
if error != nil {
            print("Geocoding error: \(error)") 
            self.locationError = true
            completionHandler(nil, error)
            return
        }
```

then call it like

```
forwardGeocoding(textField.text!){(placemarks, error) in
//your code.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `geocodeAddressString`, it is executed in a separate thread (#AppleDoc `This method submits the specified location data to the geocoding server asynchronously and returns`). So effectively you have 2 threads running in parallel. `geocodeAddressString` in thread 2 will take more time to execute since it makes a server call and the block will be executed when the call returns. During this time thread 1 will finish its execution and will print the log statements.

If you want to handle this issue, locationError if-else condition logic should be implemented in such a way that it should be triggered once your callback is executed.